# Rails: passing params hash to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

I have a user-to-user messaging system. I'm trying to pass an array of user ids to a `ConversationUser` (join table) model which would then create multiple `conversation_users` from each individual `user.id`. The two fields in `ConversationUser` are `conversation_id` and `user_id`. I'm able to initialize a single conversation user because the new `conversation_id` is being passed along to the model, but for some reason, the hash of user ids is not getting to my model. I'm getting a `Validation failed: User can't be blank`

My conversation/new view for capturing the user_ids:

```
<%= check_box_tag "conversation_user[recipient][]", user.id %> <%= user.name %><br />
```

I know this is working because part of my params that I'm receiving back are:

```
"conversation_user"=>{"recipient"=>["9", "10"]}
```

The essentials of my Rails 4 controller & strong params:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @conversation = @user.conversation_users.build
    @conversation.build_conversation.messages.build
  end

  def create
    @conv = Conversation.create!
    @conversation = @conv.conversation_users.create!(conversation_user_params)
  end

  def conversation_user_params
    params.require(:conversation_user).permit(recipient: [])
  end
```

The essentials of my ConversationUser model:

```
class ConversationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :recipient

  before_create :acquire_conversation

  validates :user_id, :conversation_id, presence: true 

  def acquire_conversation
    unless recipient.blank?
      recipient.each do |u|
        ConversationUser.create(user_id: u, conversation: conversation)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I think the problem is somewhere in my controller's `conversation_user_params`. But it also might be in the model's `before_create` method. I've been trying to fix this problem for a day now, with lots of debugging with no success. If anyone can be of assistance, I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the model. `before_create` callback is called before creating a `ConversationUser`. Let's name this created `ConversationUser` as `CURRENT`. So, before creating the `CURRENT` `ConversationUser` you loop through recipient ids and create a `ConversationUser` for each of them. The `ConversationUser`s that you are creating here are not `CURRENT` `ConversationUser`. `CURRENT` `ConversationUser` is saved after the callback is executed (after you create other `ConversationUser`s). But in this case  `CURRENT` `ConversationUser` doesn't know wich `User` it belongs to, because you pass `user_id` parameter to `ConversationUser`s that you create in `before_create` callback, but you do not pass it to `CURRENT` `ConversationUser` when it is created (when original `create!` method is executed).

To solve this problem you can override original `create!` method or not use it at all for creating `ConversationUser`s by recipient ids. Add a new method to your `Conversation` model (for example `create_conversation_users`):

**Solution**

In the controller:

```
def create
  @conv = Conversation.create!
  @conversation = @conv.create_conversation_users!(conversation_user_params[:recipient])
end
```

In the model:

```
class Conversation
  def create_conversation_users!(recipient_ids)
    return if recipient_ids.blank?

    recipient_ids.each do |recipient_id|
      conversation_users.create!(user_id: recipient_id, conversation: self)
    end
  end
end
```

You should also update `ConversationUser` model:

```
class ConversationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :conversation_id, presence: true 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the `ConversationUser`.  `before_create` callbacks are ran before a record is created in the database **BUT** after validations are ran.  To solve your issue, there's a few things you can do.  One of them was answered by Chumakoff.  Here's another option you can use.

Remove all the code inside `ConversationUser` and change `conversation_user_params` to

```
def conversation_user_params
  params[:conversation_user][recipient].map do |recipient|
    { user_id: recipient }
  end
end
```

What happens is you're passing an array of `{ user_id: 1 }` to `create!` which is the same as calling multiple `create!({ user_id: 1 })`.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. Never thought of using a do block in the params. Thank you.